# is there any way to implement dlopen by source code in C without using libdl.so?

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries

since dlopen uses libdl.so , but i am working on **standalone application** which do not use OS support, so my idea is to implement dlopen directly using coding is there any

Answer (score 0):

Loading shared libraries is intrinsically dependent on the operating
system's runtime loader and in turn on the operating system's executable file format and its process construction model. There is no OS-independent way to do it.

The [GNU source code of `dlopen`](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/dlfcn/dlopen.c.html)  is of course
freely available, but that does not make it independent of an operating system.

The maximum degree of OS independence you can achieve in C is obtained by
restricting yourself to software that you can write entirely with the
resources of the [Standard C Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header). The Standard C Library does not contain
`dlopen` or any equivalent functionality, because such functionality is
intrinsically OS-dependent.

As your question is tagged Linux, it is not quite clear why you would want your application
to be independent of OS support that is provided by Linux.

Comment: i can give you an example: if want to run python in many linux, we want to python works even on busybox based linux; therefore we need static linking, but after static linking, some python packages does not work for they need SO support.